# Receiver type () for instance message is a forward declaration issue in ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I have two protocols BaseDAO, and ICategoryDAO. ICategoryDAO adopt BaseDao. Class categoryDao adopt ICategoryDao.

The below code is the initializer method of serviceRepo class (sub class of NSObject). Here I perform the type check and etc.

```
 - (id)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            self.dict  = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [self.dict setValue:[CategoryDao description] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",[@protocol(ICategoryDao) name]]];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

the problem is Xcode always pop the error **Receiver type 'Protocol' for instance message is a forward declaration** in this call -> `[@protocol(ICategoryDao) name]`.
Im using **ARC**, it works fine on non ARC project. 
I couldn't find any solution in the internet, so finally Im here. How can I solve this issue, am I doing anything wrong here.

This is the structure of the protocols and classes;

**BaseDao**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol BaseDao <NSObject>
```

**ICategoryDAO**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BaseDao.h"

@protocol ICategoryDao <BaseDao>
```

**CategoryDAO**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ICategoryDao.h"

@interface CategoryDao : NSObject <ICategoryDao>
```

**ServiceRepo**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ServiceRepository : NSObject
```

**ServiceRepo.m**

```
#import "ServiceRepository.h"
#import "CategoryDao.h"
#import "BaseDao.h"

@implementation ServiceRepository
```

Comment: did you import the file "MockCategoryDao"

Comment: Usually an error like this means, that you need to import the .h file. So you could try importing the ICategoryDao.h directly in the SeviceRepo.m. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity i've never seen sth. like [@protocol(ICategoryDao) name]. What does the @protocol() do here?

Comment: [@protocol(ICategoryDao) name] name is the method of iCategoryDao protocol right?

Comment: i just want to store the name of the protocol as the key in the dictionary. @Pandey no it is not. name method return nsstring object used to uniquely identify the receiver . is there any other way, I can use to store the name of the protocol as key in the dict.

Comment: @Tobi ;) it just returns the name of the protocol as a string object (in non arc project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code that might help you.

```
[self.dict setValue:[CategoryDao description] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",NSStringFromProtocol(@protocol(ICategoryDao))];
```

**NSProtocolFromString**
Returns a the protocol with a given name.

```
Protocol *NSProtocolFromString (
   NSString *namestr
);
```

**Parameters**

namestr
The name of a protocol.

**Return Value**

The protocol object named by namestr, or nil if no protocol by that name is currently loaded. If namestr is nil, returns nil.

Comment: wow ur great :).. the approach is correct but the method is NSStringFromProtocol(protocol)
"NSStringFromProtocol(@protocol(ICategoryDao))"
. It just return what I wanted- the string object.

Comment: I assumed you have name protocol method, please upvote also. Glad to help you.